# EpiServer: Reference RootPage Without A Page Context

Tags: episerver

I am working on an EpiServer project and the team we are working on it with updated the code in the repository, but has not sent us an updated version of the database. As a result I am not able to load any pages, when I try to do so I get 'TypeMismatchException'. I have tried converting the page types via 'Admin -> Content Type -> Convert Page' but this does not work. Doing 'Root -> New Page' also only gives me the option to use corrupt page types. 
What I'd like to do is to create a page programmatically as a child of root but when I call

```
PageReference parent = PageReference.RootPage;
```

It tells me the 'ProviderName = null' because I have no page context.

So instead of determining the root page based on the page I'm currently on, I'd like to do the opposite, I'd like to reference the site I'm currently on, and given the site I should be able to reference the root page of that site.
Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: I don't get it. Episerver should update your database automatically on initialization. Or can't you even access the edit/admin gui?

Comment: Which Episerver version is this?

Comment: @TedNyberg 10.10.1.0

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your scenario is, but you could look into `ISiteDefinitionResolver` to get a site without a content context: http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Class-library/?documentId=cms/10/D786A9A